# min-height:100%; height:100%; not working

Tags: css

I cant figure out what is wrong with my styles.
Hope someone could help me with this.
Code example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.maindiv {
    overflow:hidden; border:#000 1px solid;
    width:450px; min-height:250px;
}
.left_inner {
    float:left; width:200px;
    min-height:100%; background:#00CC33;
}
.right_inner {
    float:left; width:150px; background:#C93;
}
</style>
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="left_inner">Left Block content</div>
    <div class="right_inner">Right block content<br />sample txt<br />sample txt</div>
</div>
```

The way it should be is like in Opera Browser (see image):
[image: Sample image]

Comment: Are you open for other positioning (`position:absolute`)?

Comment: Using inline-block is not the best way to come across doing anything. Instead, use float: left; .

Comment: He's not trying to get the elements to position, he's trying to get them to "stretch" "100%".

Comment: @MrLister: If he doesn't, he can refer to this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: a absolute positioned div makes all you want with its size. Floated elements sometimes need cear elements (helper).

Comment: yes I have doctype:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: @sharethis: You do not need to clear left floated elements. You need to clear left and right floated elements, but not both left.

Comment: Anyone that has used "float" long enough knows to never, ever, ever use it... instead use display:inline-block;vertical-align:top; and be sure to comment the white space between inline elements in the html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**The How**

http://jsfiddle.net/L9GEa/

**The Why**

1. One might intuitively assume (as I once did) that the `html` element already has a determined height, but it does not (at least in this context).  Luckily (or by design) this one element has the unique property of it's height being determinable when it is assigned a percentage height.  That is the essential concept because in order to calculate (determine) the height of any other element which is assigned a percentage height you must also be able to determine the height of it's parent.
2. Anyone that has worked with CSS and the DOM enough likely will tell you they *hate* floats.  This is because it pulls the element out of the flow, which requires additional work and thinking to juggle the effects. Instead use `display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;` with the one caveat that you will then have to add html comments around any white space between those elements.

**The CSS**

```
.maindiv {
    overflow:hidden; border:#000 1px solid;
    width:450px;min-height:250px;
    /*changes*/
    height:100%;
}
.left_inner {
    float:left; width:200px;
    min-height:100%; background:#00CC33;
    /*changes*/
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.right_inner {
    float:left; width:150px; background:#C93;
    /*changes*/
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
/*changes*/
html,
body{
    height:100%;
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="left_inner">Left Block content</div><!--
    --><div class="right_inner">Right block content<br />sample txt<br />sample txt</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, so I marked it as best answer. Thank you.

Comment: In my experience drop the html comments and set font size to 0, on your inner containers/elements set the font size and offcouse use display inline-block.. Inherrit the font size from body eg. 1rem

Answer (score 8):

add

```
html,
body {
  height:100%
}
```

at the top of your css, that works for me

EDIT: my test :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
html,
body {
height:100%;
}

.maindiv {
   overflow:hidden; border:#000 1px solid;
    width:450px; height:100%;
position:relative;
}
.left_inner {
    float:left; width:200px;
    min-height:100%; background:#00CC33;
position:relative;
}
.right_inner {
    float:left; width:150px; background:#C93;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="maindiv">
<div class="left_inner">Left Block content</div>
<div class="right_inner">Right block content<br />sample txt<br />sample txt</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <style type="text/css">
.maindiv {
    overflow:hidden; border:#000 1px solid;
    width:450px; height: auto; min-height:250px;
}
.left_inner {
    float:left; width:200px;
    min-height:100%; height: 100%; background:#00CC33;
}
.right_inner {
    float:left; width:150px; background:#C93;
}
</style>
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="left_inner">Left Block content</div>
    <div class="right_inner">Right block content<br />sample txt<br />sample txt</div>
</div>
```

Most of the time you have to apply a height of auto or 100% to the parent DIV.

Comment: @sharethis: You cannot achieve a CSS RULE at 100% if you apply the value at a pixel-base.

Comment: I think he want to left inner div to be 100% of the outer (pixel-valued) div.

Comment: And yes the pixel height for the outer div works, but the content can be much more larger that height. Thats why I need min-height or height:auto but they work only in Opera

Comment: @wzazza: Try this: I made a jsFiddle in which you can refer to... This one works. http://jsfiddle.net/xkRVs/

Comment: @wzazza: Did that jsFiddle help?

Comment: @AaronBrewer not really, my mistake I forgot to mention this too - I already have CSS `html, body {height: 100%;}` and the .maindiv block is child block of another div, well I think I'm on a right way to figure it out finally, my mistake that I didn't posted actual code of real page but created a sample one. Any way thank you very very much for your help.

Comment: @wzazza: You are very welcome, if you need anymore help, just ask. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what eventually worked for me:

For the parent container (flex flex-col min-h-screen):

```css
.parent-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh; /* or your min height */
}
```

For the child element (flex-1):

```css
.child-element {
    flex: 1;
}
```